# How to go fully fullscreen in Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, google-chrome-os

When in [immersive fullscreen](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/immersive-fullscreen) mode in Chrome OS, how do I remove the pixel garbage that remains at the top of the screen?

In the screenshot below you should be able to see a dark bar along the top. I believe this is intended to be there to show which browser tabs I have open, but to me it just looks like clutter.

[image: Chrome OS immersive mode]

Answer (score 2):

Push **F11** to enter fullscreen.

When done, press **F11** to exit fullscreen.

That's it.

Comment: I'm using a Chromebook so don't have an F11 key

Answer (score 1):

1. Chrome menu
2. Full screen (next to Zoom)
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this seems to have been entirely intentional, but has since been fixed by an update. The new behavior is to just show the tab and location bars when the cursor touches the top of the screen and not show the pixely strips.